# How to make ajax toolkit work on DNN asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit, dotnetnuke

I've read on the internet that Ajax toolkit doesn't work on asp.net web application. But there were some tips how to solve this (by adding the ajax toolki .dll file into the bin folder etc...).

But I have an Dotnetnuke asp.net web applicaton... the bin folder isn't there.. I clicked on the "Show all files and folders" but it wasn't there...

Is there any opportunity how to make ajax toolkit work on my project?

I wanted to make an autocomplete textbox but I got the error:

**Cannot Create page method "GetCompletionList" because no CodeBehind or CodeFile file was found**

Does someone now how to fix this?

Comment: You have a DotNetNuke website that doesn't have a BIN folder? If that is the case, you've got big problems as DNN wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

The bin folder is located at {InstallDirectory}/DotNetNuke/Website/Bin/. Install directory is where you've extracted the DNN website.